# Why are the letters tantan rendering an emoji?

Tags: php, html, laravel, character-encoding, emoji

I am working on a laravel web application and in the word instantaneous, the letters tantan are being replaced by an older looking emoji.

Capitalizing any of the six letters breaks the emoji. This web app is running on laravel 8.4 and this problem could not be replicated on two other apps running laravel 5.8. For now I'm just using a synonym for instantaneous but I would sure like to know what is causing this. [Here is an example of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U10cU.png)

```
<p>{!!$product->description!!}</p>
```

Comment: Do you support HTML in your Product's description field? If not, you can get around this issue by doing `{{ $product->description }}` (`{!! !!}` will parse HTML, `{{ }}` will not). I'm not sure why `tantan` would get replaced by an emoji though...

Comment: Yeah we have some trademark and registered trademark symbols like<sup>&reg;</sup> that need displayed but I also tried just {{  }} and the emoji still shows.

Comment: Ah yeah, then you'll have to use `{!! !!}` to handle those... And that's really weird; I'll try to recreate on a local project.

Comment: Laravel 8.x, with the following code: `Route::get('/test', function () { $description = 'tantan,instantaneous'; return view('test')->with(['description' => $description]); });`, then in `test.blade.php`, `{!! $description !!}`, renders: `tantan,instantaneous`... Do you have any plugins on this Laravel install or your local machine that could be replacing that text?

Comment: Nothing on my local box, but I just recently inherited this code base so I'll do a deep dive into my packages. Since you displayed it fine it definitely seems like it is something within my dev environment. Thanks for you help!

Comment: Try right clicking on your page and going to "view source" to see if the emoji is there. If it's not then copy paste the source into a new pure HTML file to see if the replacement happens again

Comment: I'm leaning towards that too TBH. I have no idea what `tantan` is though; top result is a dating app apparently , and it has a completely different logo...

Comment: Just the word instantaneous is showing up in the source code without the emoji. In a pure html file I'm now getting the word instantaneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was a problem with the font Sen that we are using tantan gets turned into the smiley face. [image]

Comment: This just raises more questions than it does answers. Ok actually just one question... why. (looks like a joke by the font creator)

Comment: Just found this on the github for the font https://github.com/philatype/Sen/issues/6 definitely not a funny joke but hey at least I know now.

Comment: If anyone is interested, there is a [fork](https://github.com/account00001/Sen) which removes the smileys.